# Alert when checkbox is checked in Javascript / Jquery automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, alert

Trying to alert the id of the radio button which is checked. But it is not alerting.

```js
// Reference the form - see HTMLFormControlsCollection
var chxGrp = document.forms.checkGroup;

chxGrp.addEventListener('change', message);

/* The Event Object is passed through, you might've seen it as 
|| "e" or "evt". How it's labelled doesn't matter because Event
|| Object is always available when you deal with the DOM.
*/
function message(event) {

  // if the node clicked is a checkbox see if it's...
  if (event.target.type === 'checkbox') {

    // ... checked then...
    if (event.target.checked) {

      wrong_id = event.target.attr('id');
      alert(wrong_id);
    } else {}
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id='checkGroup'>

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div1">
      <div class="question_div2">
        <p>Some persons can do piece of work in 12 days. Twice the number of such persons will do half of that work in, how many days.</p>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="244">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
          <label for="checka1">
            <p>1</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
          <label for="checkb1">
            <p>2</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
          <label for="checkc1">
            <p>3</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
          <label for="checkd1">
            <p>4</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
          <label for="checke1">
            <p>None of these</p>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  Question 2
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div1">
      <div class="question_div2">
        <p>In a dairy farm, 40 cows eat 40 bags of husk in 40 days. In how many days one cow will eat one bag of husk.</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="qid2" value="245">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checka2" value="A">
          <label for="checka2">
            <p>&nbsp;44</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkb2" value="B">
          <label for="checkb2">
            <p>45</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkc2" value="C">
          <label for="checkc2">
            <p>48</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkd2" value="D">
          <label for="checkd2">
            <p>40</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checke2" value="E">
          <label for="checke2">
            <p>None of these</p>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Trying to alert the id of the radio button which is checked. But it is not alerting.

Trying to alert the id of the radio button which is checked. But it is not alerting.

Trying to alert the id of the radio button which is checked. But it is not alerting.

Comment: `attr()` is a jQuery method, not a native dom element method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your code: You check for `target.type==="checkbox"` while you should check for `target.type=="radio"` and you have to use `getAttribute()` instead of `attr()`:

```js
// Reference the form - see HTMLFormControlsCollection
var chxGrp = document.forms.checkGroup;

chxGrp.addEventListener('change', message);

function message(event) {

  // if the node clicked is a checkbox see if it's...
  if (event.target.type === 'radio') {

    // ... checked then...
    if (event.target.checked) {

      wrong_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
      alert(wrong_id);
    } else {}
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id='checkGroup'>

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div1">
      <div class="question_div2">
        <p>Some persons can do piece of work in 12 days. Twice the number of such persons will do half of that work in, how many days.</p>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="244">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
          <label for="checka1">
            <p>1</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
          <label for="checkb1">
            <p>2</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
          <label for="checkc1">
            <p>3</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
          <label for="checkd1">
            <p>4</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
          <label for="checke1">
            <p>None of these</p>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  Question 2
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div1">
      <div class="question_div2">
        <p>In a dairy farm, 40 cows eat 40 bags of husk in 40 days. In how many days one cow will eat one bag of husk.</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="qid2" value="245">
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checka2" value="A">
          <label for="checka2">
            <p>&nbsp;44</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkb2" value="B">
          <label for="checkb2">
            <p>45</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkc2" value="C">
          <label for="checkc2">
            <p>48</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checkd2" value="D">
          <label for="checkd2">
            <p>40</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="option_div">
          <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="checke2" value="E">
          <label for="checke2">
            <p>None of these</p>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You could use jQuery's `attr()` function if you cast `event.target` before: `$(event.target).attr("id")`, but as your complete code is in javascript, there's no need to use jQuery here.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Does implementing full code it in JQuery will make fast and small code?

Comment: @vipejo Though the difference won't be much to consider, it should be faster to use javascript instead of jQuery. jQuery is just a javascript library and needs to get interpreted, so using pure javascript is faster.

Comment: @vipejo It would be a bit smaller as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/py9mux8L/